# Why does reading from the master end of a PTY terminal hang?

Tags: python, gdb, pty

I am writing a small application that wraps GDB to issue/parse commands/output through a PTY. I currently use two PTYs pairs to communicate with the GDB child process: master/slave for reading from GDB stdout/stderr and master2/slav2 for writing to GDB stdin:

```
        # open pseudo-terminal to interact with subprocess
        master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
        master_fd2, slave_fd2 = pty.openpty()
        self.master_fd, self.slave_fd = master_fd, slave_fd
        self.master_fd2, self.slave_fd2 = master_fd2, slave_fd2

        # for keeping track of the current index in the read buffer in case of partial reads with recvuntil
        self.partial_buf = None
        try:
            self.proc = Popen(command,
                    preexec_fn=os.setsid,
                    stdin=self.slave_fd2,
                    stdout=self.slave_fd,
                    stderr=self.slave_fd)
            
            # connect slave2 to stdin
            self.proc.stdin = os.fdopen(os.dup(self.slave_fd2), 'r+b', 0)
            # connect slave to stdout/stderr
            self.proc.stdout = os.fdopen(os.dup(self.slave_fd), 'r+b', 0)
            self.proc.stderr = os.fdopen(os.dup(self.slave_fd), 'r+b', 0)
```

I implemented a simple recvuntil function that reads the output from master until a certain string is encountered, and the write function that writes some bytes to master2:

```
def recvuntil(self, stop):
        output = bytes()
        while True:
            # read from master_fd connected to child stdout,stderr
            b = os.read(self.master_fd, 10000)
            print("bytes: ", b)
            if stop.encode("utf-8") in b:
                return output

   def write(self, data):
        self.last_write = bytes(data, encoding="utf-8")
        try:
            # write to master_fd connected to child stdin
            os.write(self.master_fd, bytes(data.encode("utf-8")))
        except IOError as e:
            print("IOError {}".format(e))
```

The following code issues command to GDB and reads the output:

```
END_PARSE = "info win"
gdb = Process(["gdb", "ls"])
gdb.write("r\n")
gdb.write(f"{END_PARSE}\n")
output = gdb.recvuntil(f"{END_PARSE}\n").decode('utf-8').split('\n')
```

However, when I run the above commands, the output from the console seem to hang forever on the read for self.master_fd. Looking at the output, it seems like there is a missing pair of newlines that are not getting parsed from GDB. Any ideas on what is happening to the newlines that should have been prined to the slave2 stdout?

```
bytes:  b'Reading symbols from ls...'
bytes:  b'(no debugging symbols found)...done.\r\n'
bytes:  b'\x1b[1;31mgef\xe2\x9e\xa4  \x1b[0m'
bytes:  b'r'
bytes:  b'\r\n'
bytes:  b'Starting program: /bin/ls \r\n'
bytes:  b'[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]\r\n'
bytes:  b'[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]\r\n'
bytes:  b'[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]\r\nUsing host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".\r\n'
bytes:  b'[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]\r\n'
bytes:  b'[Inferior 1 (process 9422) exited normally]\r\n'
bytes:  b'\x1b[1;31mgef\xe2\x9e\xa4  \x1b[0m'
bytes:  b'info win\r\n'
bytes:  b'\x1b[1;31mgef\xe2\x9e\xa4  \x1b[0m'
```

Comment: Could you mark on in the final output where you think there should be additional newline characters?

Comment: Sorry, information is kinda of complete, will update in a few